# Что обозначает ошибка?

Tags: javascript

> Uncaught JavaScript exception [XML cannot be the whole program] in `http://127.0.0.1:8888/second.html?callback=isc.Comm._scriptIncludeReply_0`, line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь.

Проблема решилась всего за одну строчку: в файле second.html вставил эту строку:

```
isc.Comm._scriptIncludeReply_0(4444)
```

И все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка выскакивает, когда XML не валидный. То есть где-то есть незакрытый тэг или что-либо ещё.

Answer (score 0):

Такое бывает, когда вы пишете тэг скрипт в тексте, который трактуется как JavaScript. Например, внутри JS-файла:

[SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771521/xml-cannot-be-the-whole-program), [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371189/what-does-firebug-xml-cannot-be-the-whole-program-error-message-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Если javascript генерируется чем-то, надо посмотреть, что в итоге сгенерировалось, нет ли в скрипте какого-нибудь мусора. И кроме того, посмотреть нет ли в самом скрипте тэгов

```
<script></script>
```

они там не нужны.